# Android Gradle SourceSet Resources not copying base dir

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently working on automating an android build via gradle but my build.gradle file isn't copying the entire res/ or assets/ dirs into my produced apk.

Clarification:
The contents of the needed `res/` & `assets/` dirs are copied into the apk, but the actual `res/` and `assets/` dirs are nowhere to be found.  For this automation to match the manual process in place, I need a seemless transition from manual build process to automated build process. (no difference in produced apk)

I know it has to be how I'm addressing the sourceSets and resources, but I can't find any direction/advice on what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src','../res','../assets']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***************"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

My directory structure(loosely represented):

```
AppBase/
+res/
+assets/
-gradle files
+AndroidApp
    +src/
    -gradle files
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. I just did `File > New > Folder > Assets Folder`, it made me pick `src/main/assets`, then I built an APK and both the `res/` and `assets/` folder are in the top-level of the APK file. I didn't touch Gradle at all and it was a brand new project, so I had whatever the default Gradle file is...

Comment: Agreed, making a new project is like heaven compared to migrating this mess of an app from eclipse to android studio without making any logical directory structure changes.  Old problem of having too many independent devs working on the same project without code review..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be doing something like this, though, I am not too sure about the relative paths.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res','../res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets', '../assets']
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Appreciate it, @cricket_007 !!